# Google fusion table query error - time comparison

Tags: javascript, html, google-fusion-tables

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAB-b8aFHZ7a8tICmAbPEhQgQ2Uvf8t1zg&libraries=visualization,places&sensor=false"></script>
<script src="https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=16IJZkJaz4jlZZnZYsiQEG4POvB0eHBEfuVFGWb3m"></script>
<style type="text/css">
html {height:100%}
body {height: 100%; margin:500;padding:0}
#title {height:80px; margin-top:20px; }
#options{height:50px;}
#time1{width:95px}
#time2{width:95px}
#googleMap{margin-left:325px; margin-top:50px; width: 950px; height: 800px} 
#type-selector {color: #fff;background-color: #4d90fe;padding: 5px 11px 0px 11px;}
#type-selector label {font-family: Roboto;font-size: 13px;font-weight: 300;}
.controls {
        margin-top: 16px;
        border: 1px solid transparent;
        border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        height: 32px;
        outline: none;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
      }
#pac-input {
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
        width: 400px;
        font-family: Roboto;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: 300;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
      }

      #pac-input:focus {
        border-color: #4d90fe;
        margin-left: -1px;
        padding-left: 14px;  /* Regular padding-left + 1. */
        width: 401px;
      }

</style>
</head>

<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

var map;   //global variable so can be used by all functions to update the map
var tableid='16IJZkJaz4jlZZnZYsiQEG4POvB0eHBEfuVFGWb3m'; //fusion tableid to access the database table
function initialize(){
    google.maps.visualRefresh = true;
var mapProp = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(19.119118,73.048439),
  zoom:11,
  scaleControl: true,
  streetViewControl:false,
  mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

  //create a new map in div element
  map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);

  //add bounds to display search results within mumbai
 var defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
      new google.maps.LatLng(19.300572, 72.768631),
      new google.maps.LatLng(18.975029, 73.186455));
      map.fitBounds(defaultBounds);

  // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
  var input =(document.getElementById('pac-input'));
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

  var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox((input));

  // Listen for the event fired when the user selects an item from the
  // pick list. Retrieve the matching places for that item.
  google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function() {
    var places = searchBox.getPlaces();
    var markers = [];

    for (var i = 0, marker; marker = markers[i]; i++) {
      marker.setMap(null);
    }

    // For each place, get the icon, place name, and location.
    markers = [];
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    for (var i = 0, place; place = places[i]; i++) {
      var image = {
        url: place.icon,
        size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
      };

      // Create a marker for each place.
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        icon: image,
        title: place.name,
        position: place.geometry.location
      });

      markers.push(marker);
    bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
    }
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  });

  // Bias the SearchBox results towards places that are within the bounds of the current map's viewport.
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
    var bounds = map.getBounds();
    searchBox.setBounds(bounds);
   });  
}  //end of initialize
var i=0;

 function allmarks(opt)
{
    switch(opt)
    {
    case "None":
    document.getElementById("Timerange").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("Raterange").style.display = "none"; 
    initialize();
    break;

    case "All":
    document.getElementById("Timerange").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("Raterange").style.display = "none"; 
    while (i!=0){layer.setMap(null);i--;}

    layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    query: {select: 'Latitude',
      from: tableid}});

  layer.setMap(map);
  i++;
  break;

  case "Time" : document.getElementById("Timerange").style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById("Raterange").style.display = "none"; 
                layer.setMap(null);
                break;

  case "Rating" : document.getElementById("Raterange").style.display = "block";
                  document.getElementById("Timerange").style.display = "none"; 
                  layer.setMap(null);
                  break;
    } //end of switch
  } //end of allmarks


  function timefunc()
  {     //function to retrive the input values and  fire query on fusion table
      var x = document.getElementById("time1").value;
      var y = document.getElementById("time2").value;

      var whereClause = 'Time >'+x+' AND Time<='+y; 
      alert(whereClause);

      while (i!=0){layer.setMap(null);i--;}

     layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    query: {
      select: 'Latitude,Longitude,Time,Rating',
      from: tableid,
      where: whereClause
    }
  });
  layer.setMap(map);
  i++;
      }

    function ratefunc()
    {   //function to retrive the input values and  fire query on fusion table
      var k = document.getElementById("rate1").value;
      var l = document.getElementById("rate2").value;
      var a=1;
      var b=5;
      while (i!=0){layer.setMap(null);i--;}


      if(k>5||l>5)
      {alert("Please enter a value between 1 and 5");}
      if(k>l)
      {alert("Please enter a valid range");}

       layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    query: {
      select: 'Latitude,Longitude,Time,Rating',
      from: tableid,
    where:"Rating >"+k+" AND Rating <="+l
    }
  });
  layer.setMap(map);
  i++; }
</script>

<body onload="initialize()">

<div id="title"><h1><center> Visualisation of Parking Requests</center></h1> </div>

<div id="options"> 
<form>
<h3 align="center">Display:
<select name="sortby" onChange="allmarks(this.value)">
<option id="None" value="None">None</option>
<option id="All" value="All"  >All</option>
<option id="Time" value="Time">Time</option>
<option id="Rating" value="Rating">Rating</option>
</select>


<div id="Timerange" style="display:none">
Enter a Time range: <input id="time1" type="time" name="time1">
to : <input id="time2" type="time" name="time2">
<input type="button" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="timefunc()"/>
</div>

<div id="Raterange" style="display:none">
Enter a Rating range : <input id="rate1" type="number" name="rating1" min="0" max="5" step="0.1" value="1">
to : <input id="rate2"  type="number" name="rating2" min="0" max="5" step="0.1" value="5">

<input type="button" name="submit1" value="Submit" onclick="ratefunc()"/>
</div>
</h3></form></div>

<input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
<div id="googleMap"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

I am developing a simple html program that has one drop-down menu with the options None , All , Time and Rating. I am using a Google fusion table with columns having random generated values. The columns are Cid,latitude,longitude,time and rating.

When I choose 'All'. all the points in the Google fusion table are displayed on the map,when i choose 'Rating' I can enter a specific range of values and then query using those constraints. I am facing problems when i try to do the same with 'Time'. In the function 'timefunc()' the where clause of the query does not execute correctly. I have tried using Fusion table's publish option after carrying out filtering but that did not help.

How do i overcome this problem? I need it to display the time entered by the user in the input box but i just cant seem to construct the appropriate query that it will run and display the proper results.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found details about it in the documentation, but as it seems you must explicitly pass the values as strings:

```
var whereClause = "Time >'"+x+"' AND Time<='"+y+"'";
```

Note: you must use the format `hh:ss` in the input-fields

Comment: Thank you ! It works just fine. In the input field I am using the Time type offered by HTML5 so it is that format by default.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution I found for this problem was to split the input so 13:30 would be split into 13,30 and stored into an array. The fusion tables also need to have separate columns such as hour,minute and then we query them individually. Here is the updated timefunc() -

Note : The fusion table that I am using is different the new fusion table ID is -'17rCPfwugHVJrCbEHGKNOp21e7UsVQxjubUhRZSch' it is stored in a variable called tableid1.

```
function timefunc()
{ 
  var x = document.getElementById("time1").value;
  var y = document.getElementById("time2").value;

  var ax=x.split(":");
  var by=y.split(":");

  var whereClause = 'hour >='+ax[0]+' AND hour <='+by[0]+' AND minute >='+ax[1]+' AND minute <='+by[1]; 

  while (i!=0){layer.setMap(null);i--;}

 layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
query: {
  select: 'Latitude',
  from: tableid1,
  where: whereClause
  }
 });
 layer.setMap(map);
  i++;
  }
```